# odoo 10 custom report ..sum lines qty..by product_id

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

odoo 10 report...question ...
why get_qty can't send data to docargs?
i want lines data...qty sum...by product_id is same...
why xml t-foreach="data" can get any data for me

```
class ReportStockInventorySummary(models.AbstractModel):
            _name = 'report.stock.inventory.summary'

            def get_qty(self, docids):
                docs = self.env["stock.inventory"].browse(docids)
                lines = self.env["stock.inventory.line"].search([('inventory_id', '=', docs.id)])
                data = list()
                show_data = list()
                for x in lines:
                    data.append({
                        "line_location_id": x.location_id,
                        "line_product_id": x.product_id,
                        "line_product_qty": x.product_qty,
                    })

                for i, g in groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x['line_product_id']):
                    show_data.append([i, sum(v['line_product_qty'] for v in g)])

            @api.multi
            def render_html(self, docids, data):
                report = self.env['report']
                self.model = self.env.context.get('active_model')
                docs = self.env["stock.inventory"].browse(docids)


                docargs = {
                    'doc_ids': docids,
                    'doc_model': self.model,
                    'docs': docs,
                    'data': self.get_qty //* i want sum product_qty by product_id *//
                }
                return report.render("stock_inventory_report.report_stock_inventory_template", docargs)

            <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <odoo>
            <data>
                <template id="report_stock_inventory_template">
                    <t t-call="report.html_container">
                        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                            <div class="page">
                                <h2>Report title</h2>
                                <p>This object's name is
                                    <span t-field="o.name"/>
                                </p>
                                <table class="table table-condensed">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
                                                <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                                                <th class="text-right"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
    <!---- why t-foreach="data" cant show any data for me -->
                                        <tr t-foreach="data" t-as="line">
                                            <td><span t-esc="line['line_location_id']" /></td>
                                            <td><span t-esc="line['line_product_id']" /></td>
                                            <td><span t-esc="line['line_product_qty']" /></td>
                                        </tr>


                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                        </t>
                    </t>
                </template>
            </data>
        </odoo>
```

I want from stock.inventory.lines in qweb display data and field (location_id, product_id, product_qty) what do I need to change in above py and how do I create view?

Any similar examples for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the method `get_qty` to `data`, but you should call it instead.

`'data': self.get_qty(doc_ids)`

Even better is not to use `data` key, because it already is used by another process. Just make your own key and use it in your report template instead of data:

`'get_qty': self.get_qty(doc_ids)`

And your method is not returning anything resp. `None`. I think `show_data` is your return result so just return it.

```py
def get_qty(self, docids):
    show_data = []
    # ...
    return show_data
```

Comment: Thanks....I have tried 'data': show_data ...But...result is None..only docs data show in my pdf data